# CollapsingToolbarLayout not visible when specific fragment is active?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I have only one activity in my project and that is `MainActivity` and I have implemented a collapsing toolbar layout on my MainActivity's layout:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                ads:expandedTitleMarginBottom="24dp"
                ads:expandedTitleMargin="16dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_img"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    ads:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo"
                    ads:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    ads:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="@integer/material_motion_duration_long_2" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    ads:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    ads:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

and I wanted the toolbar to be visible only when a few specific fragments are active on the screen and to achieve that functionality, I've implemented the logic like this:

**BaseActivity.kt:**

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
  package com.pavan.teja.example
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.WindowManager
    import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
    import androidx.navigation.NavController
    import androidx.navigation.NavDestination
    import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
    import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    import com.pavan.teja.example.BaseApplicationStuff.BaseActivity
    import com.pavan.teja.example.Utils.Utilities
    import com.pavan.teja.example.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
    import timber.log.Timber
    
    class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener, NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
    
        private lateinit var utilities: Utilities
        private lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding
        private var navController: NavController? = null
        private lateinit var appToolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        private lateinit var appBarLayout: AppBarLayout
        private lateinit var menu: Menu
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    
             utilities = Utilities()
            //Apply security by blocking screenshots
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
            )
    
            //Setting up AppBar
            appToolbar = activityMainBinding.toolbar
            //setting AppBar Layout
            appBarLayout = activityMainBinding.appBar
            appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this)
            setSupportActionBar(appToolbar)
    
            //Fragment Navigation setup
            val navHostFragment =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(activityMainBinding.container.id)
            navController = navHostFragment?.findNavController()
            navController?.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    
        }
    
        override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?, verticalOffset: Int) {
            var isShow = false
            var scrollRange = -1
    
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange!!
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                isShow = true
    //            showOption(R.id.action_info)
            } else if (isShow) {
                isShow = false
    //            hideOption(R.id.action_info)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.memu, menu)
            if (menu != null) {
                this.menu = menu
            }
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    
            when (item.itemId) {
    
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    
        private fun hideOption(id: Int) {
            val item: MenuItem = menu.findItem(id)
            item.isVisible = false
        }
    
        private fun showOption(id: Int) {
            val item: MenuItem = menu.findItem(id)
            item.isVisible = true
        }
    
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            return navController!!.navigateUp()
        }
    
        override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController,
            destination: NavDestination,
            arguments: Bundle?
        ) {
            when (navController?.currentDestination?.label) {
                "SplashScreenFragment" -> {
    
                    activityMainBinding.appBar.visibility = View.GONE
    //                supportActionBar?.hide()
                    activityMainBinding.container.fitsSystemWindows = true
                    utilities.hideSystemUI(window, activityMainBinding.root)
                }
                "InitiationCheckFragment" -> {
                    activityMainBinding.appBar.visibility = View.GONE
    //                supportActionBar?.hide()
                    activityMainBinding.container.fitsSystemWindows = true
                    utilities.hideSystemUI(window, activityMainBinding.root)
                }
                "NotInitiatedFragment" -> {
                    activityMainBinding.appBar.visibility = View.GONE
    //                supportActionBar?.hide()
                    activityMainBinding.container.fitsSystemWindows = true
                    utilities.hideSystemUI(window, activityMainBinding.root)
                }
                else -> {
    //                activityMainBinding.container.fitsSystemWindows = false
                    supportActionBar?.show()
    
                    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
                    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
                    supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.app_bar_title)
    
    //                val title = getString(R.string.app_bar_title)
    //                appToolbar.toolbar.title = title
    //                appToolbar.showOverflowMenu()
    //                supportActionBar?.title =
    //                    HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<big>${title}</big>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    //                activityMainBinding.container.fitsSystemWindows = false
                    utilities.showSystemUI(window, activityMainBinding.root)
                }
            }
    
            Timber.d("current active fragment ${navController?.currentDestination?.label}")
        }
    }
```

Here's the **Utilities** class code:

```
 class Utilities {
     fun hideSystemUI(window: Window, mainContainer: View) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, mainContainer).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }

    fun showSystemUI(window: Window, mainContainer: View) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(
            window,
            mainContainer
        ).show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
```

**themes.xml:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyCustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#f21505</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#ed594e</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#f25c05</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#f58b4e</item>
        <!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>-->
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

**night/themes.xml:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyCustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#f21505</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#ed594e</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#f25c05</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#f58b4e</item>
        <!--        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>-->
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

The app doesn't crash but it doesn't show the app bar when the fragments where I wanted the appbar to be visible.

Now that the toolbar layout is on MainActivity, I haven't implemented anything on the fragments regarding the toolbar. I'm changing the  fragments using navController.

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem and make the appbar visible on top of the fragments?

Thank you.